# angular js routeProvider doesn't work in nodewebkit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-webkit, route-provider

I'm using nodewebkit with a angualrjs and i have some problems with the routeProvider , this simple example works fine in the browser but when i use nodewebkit and click in some link with a link to a router this does nothing

```
 var musicPlayer = angular.module("musicPlayer", ["ngRoute"]);


    musicPlayer.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            when("/",{
                templateUrl: "/app/views/albums.html",
                controller: "indexCtrl"
            }).
            when("/album/:id", {
                templateUrl: "/app/views/album.html",
                controller: "albumCtrl"
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/parking"
            });


    });


    musicPlayer.controller("indexCtrl", function($scope){
        var albums = [
            {
                id: 1,
                band: "megadeth",
                name: "Rust in peace"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                band: "megadeth",
                name: "Peace sells"
            }
        ];

        $scope.albums = albums;
    });

    musicPlayer.controller("albumCtrl", function($scope){
        console.log("album")
    });
```

in the nodewebkit devtools the ng-repeat from angular create this urls **unsafe:app://host/app/views/index.html#/album/1** any idea?

AngularJS v1.2.0

**Well , i fix adding this in the config**

```
 // Add app: protocol for node-webkit
    .config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|app):/);
    }]);
```

Comment: you may need to answer this question and flag it as a correct answer instead of updating the question :)